# Login my website use google api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client, google-authentication

I am trying to login my website using google.I put the code in jsp page html code:

```
<span id="signinButton">
 <span
class="g-signin"
data-callback="signinCallback"
data-clientid="*********"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
 </span>
 </span>
```

javascript code:

```
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();

 function signinCallback(authResult) {
      if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
        // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
        document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
              'userId' : 'me'
            });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
              console.log('ID: ' + resp.id);
              console.log('Display Name: ' + resp.displayName);
              console.log('Image URL: ' + resp.image.url);
              console.log('Profile URL: ' + resp.url);
            });
      } else {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
        // Possible error values:
        //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
        //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
        //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
      }
    }
```

If i put data-scope address http i got error:

400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

request_visible_actions not allowed for scope http://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

400. That’s an error.

Error: origin_mismatch

Application: Project Default Service Account

How to solve this problem.I want user profile details use google api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"` make sure the exact URL and path the code is executing on is registered on your applications list of allowed origins. Change scope to `data-scope="profile"`.

Comment: I remove that one i got error 400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[http://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login]}

Comment: but now i tested localhost not online

Comment: I put data-scope="profile" i got error:400. That’s an error.

Error: origin_mismatch

Application: Project Default Service Account

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have to make sure the apps settings has the correct origin set.

Comment: Again one problem,I click g+ signin button it's working fine no error showing but in browser console show one error message.[Callback function named "signinCallback" not found].the return call back function not called.how to solve this problem?please help me...